# Error loading modules dynamically

Tags: reactjs, importerror, isomorphic-javascript, react-starter-kit, dynamic-routing

In my Page/Page.js component, I am trying to dynamically load modules in REACT based on an array of modules called "modules". Currently I have all modules listed and I create components for each one in the modules array.

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './Page.css';

import Feedback from '../Feedback';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import Header from '../Header';
import Layout from '../Layout';
import Link from '../Link';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import Intro from '../Intro';

const importedModules = {
  Feedback,
  Footer,
  Header,
  Layout,
  Link,
  Navigation,
  Intro,
};

class Page extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    modules: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      module: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })).isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { modules } = this.props;
    let key = 0;
    const items = modules.map((item) => {
      key += 1;
      return React.createElement(importedModules[item.module], {
        key,
      });
    });
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

I started looking at this blog 
http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/

I tried to import using *System.import*

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './Page.css';

import Feedback from '../Feedback';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import Header from '../Header';
import Layout from '../Layout';
import Link from '../Link';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import Intro from '../Intro';

const importedModules = {
  Feedback,
  Footer,
  Header,
  Layout,
  Link,
  Navigation,
  Intro,
};

function loadRoute(cb) {
 return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    modules: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      module: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })).isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { modules } = this.props;
    let key = 0;
    const items = modules.map((item) => {
      key += 1;
      System.import('../'+String(item.module)).then((cb) => {
        console.log(loadRoute(cb));
        return React.createElement(loadRoute(cb), {
          key,
        });
      });
    });
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

I get errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/addons' in '/Users/jgs/Projects/react/MyApp/node_modules/enzyme/build'
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js 41:16-39 42:46-69
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Layout/Layout.test.js
 @ ./src/components async ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./src/components/Page/Page.js
 @ ./src/client.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client.js
ERROR in ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactContext' in '/Users/jgs/Projects/react/MyApp/node_modules/enzyme/build'
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js 43:23-56
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Layout/Layout.test.js
 @ ./src/components async ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./src/components/Page/Page.js
 @ ./src/client.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client.js
ERROR in ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment' in '/Users/jgs/Projects/react/MyApp/node_modules/enzyme/build'
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js 73:4-45
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Layout/Layout.test.js
 @ ./src/components async ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./src/components/Page/Page.js
 @ ./src/client.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client.js
```

also in the node console I get this:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Cannot find module './Intro'.
```

Here is my directory tree

```
$ tree -d src/
src/
├── components
│   ├── Feedback
│   ├── Footer
│   ├── Header
│   ├── Intro
│   ├── Layout
│   ├── Link
│   ├── Navigation
│   └── Page
├── core
│   └── fetch
├── data
│   ├── queries
│   └── types
└── routes
    ├── about
    ├── admin
    ├── contact
    ├── error
    ├── home
    ├── login
    ├── notFound
    ├── page
    ├── privacy
    └── register
```

Comment: I found this comment that might help you, but it's not much of a viable solution. Theres also another person that commented 2 down that might be of use. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/503#issuecomment-265016431